# Syntax error trying to write to a text file in python

Tags: python, file, text, input

My program is a prefect application quiz and at the begining of the quiz students need to enter their: `Name`, `Lastname` and `School class`. At the end of the quiz the program will calculate the score and if they have passed then their details will be displayed on screen and written to a text file. At this point the user will be asked to write a short statement about why they should be considered to become a prefect and this will also be printed onto the file. The user should be able to print the file off as a receipt that they have passed the prefect application quiz.

This is my code but it is not working, can anyone explain why?

```
class Score_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        score_str = str(sum(parent.score_per_question.values()))
        self.score = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = "You're score was: " + score_str)
        self.score.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


        if int(score_str) >= 3:
            print("Pass")

            self.prefect = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = "You have passed, well done! You can now become a prefect.")
            self.prefect.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            self.name = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_name)
            self.name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            self.surname = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_surname)
            self.surname.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            self.tutor = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = student_tutor_group)
            self.tutor.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

            receipt_printoff = open("data.txt", "w")
            receipt_printoff.write(student_name, " ",student_surname)
            receipt_printoff.write(student_tutor_group)
            statement = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("User data", "Enter something about yourself")
            receipt_printoff.write((" ",statement)
```

The problem appears on this next line where there is a 'syntax' error:

```
        with open("data.txt", "r") as l
            for lines in l:
                student_name2, student_surname2, statement2 = lines.split()
                namelabel = label(self, text=student_name2)
                namelabel.pack()
                surnamelable = label(self, text=student_surname2)
                surnamelable.pack()
                Userinfolabel = label(self, text=statement2)
                Userinfolabel.pack()
    else:
        print("Fail")

        self.fail = tk.Label(self, width=80, height=4, text = "Unfortunately you have not scored highly enough to be considered for a prefect position.")
        self.fail.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: You forgot `receipt_printoff.close()`, or better use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) statement when dealing with file objects.

Comment: Well what is the syntax error?

Comment: @dimo414: On the line before where the OP thinks it is..

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes I can see it, I wanted OP to tell us what (s)he's seeing.

Comment: What is a `prefect application quiz`?

Comment: In high school there are prefects, and this quiz has scenarios that determine whether or not the person can become a prefect.

Answer (score 4):

You have **two** syntax errors:

```
        receipt_printoff.write((" ",statement)
        #  -----------------------------------^
    with open("data.txt", "r") as l
    # -----------------------------^
```

You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` *and* a `:` colon.

The first line is what is causing your immediate syntax error, but once you fix that you'll run into the second error.

You probably wanted to write a space and the statement; use string concatenation for that:

```
receipt_printoff.write(student_name + " " + student_surname)
```

and

```
receipt_printoff.write(" " + statement)
```

or use string formatting; you *probably* want to add some newlines too:

```
receipt_printoff.write('{} {}\n'.format(student_name, student_surname))
# ...
receipt_printoff.write(' {}\n'.format(statement))
```

because `file.write()` is nothing like `print()`; it won't convert values to string for you, and can only take one argument at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`with open("data.txt", "r") as l` should be `with open("data.txt", "r") as l:` (note the colon).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a colon from the end of `with open("data.txt", "r") as l:`.